# Give two links in one HTML <td> tag

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Here is one `<td>` tag that has the link to go to **marks/details/index/someId**,

```
<td>   
    <a href="<?php
        echo $this->url('marks/details',array('action'=>'index','id'=>$item['studentAcademicId']))  
    ?>">  
    <?php
        if(($item['marksObtained'])!= Null )
        { 
            echo $item['marksObtained'];
        } 
        else {echo 'Add Marks'; };
    ?>
</td>
```

I want to add another link, in this same `<td>` after `else {echo 'Add Marks'; }` which would go to another link e.g **Marks/details/addfromsession/someId**

Comment: Well, what stops you? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I suggest just find url before `td` tag and then assign at last

Comment: well, tried some combinations, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the correct way to pass two links in one HTML `<td>` tag.

```
<?php foreach ($this->data as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php if(isset( $item['marksObtained']) &&  $item['marksObtained'] > 0){?>
                <a href="<?=$this->url( 'marks/details', array('action'=>'index', 'id'=>$item['studentAcademicId']))?>">
                    <?php echo $item['marksObtained']; ?></a>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <a href="<?=$this->url( 'marks/details', array('action'=>'add', 'id'=>$item['studentAcademicId']))?>">
                    Add Marks</a>
            <?php }?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

> If condition is true, one link is passed, else the other link is passed, So now we have two  tags that are working exactly to the question.

Answer (score 1):

anchor tag is not closed  after this you can add anchor. like as below

```
<td>   
    <a href="
            <?php echo $this->url(
                'marks/details',array('action'=>'index','id'=>$item['studentAcademicId']))?>">
<?php  if(($item['marksObtained'])!= Null )
    {  echo
   $item['marksObtained'];} 
         else {echo 'Add Marks'; };?> </a>
<a href="SOME LINK">SOME TEXT</a>
 </td>
```

Comment: The last <a> reference tag that you added will be written inside php code, and in href" HERE", i have to write php again, so it seems like this

Php iside Html inside Php iside Html.

Comment: When i put semicolon after </a> it cause error of expression result unused